# Training an Hugginface model without n_epochs

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I would like to train from scratch a   `RobertaForMaskedLM` in Hugginface.
However I would like to not specify any stopping time, but to stop only when there is no more improvement in the training. There is a way to do that? I know that the n_epochs in the  `Trainer`   is default 3.

Thanks